# Fileupload of PrimeFaces is not working in my liferay portlet?

Tags: primefaces, liferay

I am using primefaces 3.3.1 and liferay 6.

In my portlet I want to add fileUpload for primefaces. But each time whenever my page loads this primefaces component is not visible through firebug. I need to make its display to block.

Also, any components below the fileUpload which consists of javascript method or ajax is not working.

I have noticed that in firebug whenever my page loads it shows me one error such as

```
this.form.fileUpload is not a function
```

I guess due to this error my fileUpload is not working. But I am not able to to fix it.

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" fileLimit="3"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your primefaces to version 3.5 and add commons-fileupload to your project

Answer (score 0):

I think it caused by you didn't add the commons-fileupload and commons-io in your project lib. Also, don't forget do define FileUploadFilter in your web.xml.

Let me show you how i did file upload in my primefaces before, hope this example can solve your problem.

My xhtml page :

```
<p:fileUpload allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(csv)$/" fileUploadListener="#{fileBean.handleFileUpload}"/>
```

My FileBean.java :

```
public class FileBean {
private UploadedFile file;

public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) throws Exception {
    file = event.getFile();

    InputStream input = file.getInputstream();
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:/UploadedFile/", file.getFileName()));

    IOUtils.copy(input, output);
}
```

Add this to your web.xml :

```
<filter>
<filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
<filter-class>
    org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter
</filter-class>
</filter>
```

And as I said before, add commons-fileupload and commons-io to your project lib.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue in Liferay Portal 6.0.x.

Can you add this code to web.xml and try it?

```
<!-- Workaround for PrimeFaces 3.2: -->
<context-param>
<param-name>com.liferay.faces.bridge.primeFileUploadForceResourceURL</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

[Here is link](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/FACES-308) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything else concerning web.xml,pom.xml,... I came back to the obvious things :-)

Maybe you are just forgetting to wrap an form around your upload elements:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

<p:fileUpload mode="simple" value="#{mgr.file}"/>

<p:commandButton value="Hochladen" ajax="false" onclick="start();" 
                action="#{mgr.uploadBescheid(bescheidTyp)}" update="growl"/>  
</h:form>
```

Without that point it won't work...